# Don't understand the reason for "Expected a type" compilation error in a method declaration, when the type is defined

Tags: objective-c, ios, types, enums

This code won't compile and generates the error message "Expected a type". As the type is declared right above I don't understand why.

```
enum TMyType
{
    Etype1,
    Etype2
};

@interface Factory : NSObject

+ (void) foo: (TMyType) actionType;

@end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To define a custom type, the correct way is with a typedef.

Try...

```
typedef enum 
{
    Etype1,
    Etype2
} TMyType;
```

EDIT:
Not long after this question was asked and answered, Apple came out with a new way to do enumerated data types.  [Here's](http://nshipster.com/ns_enum-ns_options/) an in-depth article on it.

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, TMyType) {
    Etype1,
    Etype2
};
```

Answer (score 3):

```
+ (void) foo: (enum TMyType) actionType;
```

or use `.mm` (and retag question with `objective-c++`).

Comment: Thanks, what does .mm represent?

Comment: @Mungbeans it represents an objective-c++ source file. In C/Obj-C, an enum must be fully typed, e.g. `enum myType myArg = myEnumValue;`. In C++, you can simply reference it like this: `myType myArg = myEnumValue;`, as the C++ compiler will infer the `enum` automatically.

Comment: Not that I object the downvote, but I'd appreciate an explanation.